# raster images stacked recursively

Tags: r, time-series

I have the following problem, please.
I need to read recursively raster images, stack and store them in a file with different names (e.g. name1.tiff, name2.tiff, ...)

I tried the following:

```
 for (i in 10) {
   fn <- system.file ("external / test.grd", package = "raster")
   fn <-stack (fn) # not sure if this idea can work.
   fnSTACK[,, i] <-fn
 }
```

here expect a result of the form:

> dim (fnSTACK)
>
> [1] 115 80 10

or something like that

but it didn't work.

Actually, I have around 300 images that I have to be store with different names.
The purpose is to extract time series information (if you know another method or suggestions I would appreciate it)

Any suggestions are welcomed. Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: You want the 300 images stacked in a single multi-layerd raster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would first do is put all your *.tiff in a single folder. Then read all their names into a list. Stack them and then write a multi-layered raster. I'm assuming all the images have the same extent and projection.

```
    ### Load necessary packages
library(tiff)
library(raster)
library(sp)
library(rgdal)   #I cant recall what packages you might need so this is probably 
library(grid)    # overkill
library(car)

############ function extracts the last n characters from a string  
############ without counting the last m
subs <- function(x, n=1,m=0){
  substr(x, nchar(x)-n-m+1, nchar(x)-m)
  }



setwd("your working directory path") # you set your wd to were all your images are
filez <- list.files() # creates a list with all the files in the wd
no <- length(filez) # amount of files found
imagestack <- stack() # you initialize your raster stack

for (i in 1:no){

  if (subs(filez[i],4)=="tiff"){

  image <- raster(filez[i]) # fill up raster stack with only the tiffs

  imagestack <- addLayer(imagestack,image)
   }
}

writeRaster(imagestack,filename="output path",options="INTERLEAVE=BAND",overwrite=TRUE)
# write stack
```

I did not try this, but it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is rather vague and it would have helped if you had provided a full example script such that it could be more easily understood. You say you need to read several (probably not recursively?) raster images (files, presumably) and create a stack. Then you need to store them in files with different names. That sounds like copying the files to new files with a different names, and there are R functions for that, but that is probably not what you intended to ask.

if you have a bunch of files (with full path names or in the working directory), e.g. from list.files()

```
 f <- system.file ("external/test.grd", package = "raster")
 ff <- rep(f, 10)
```

you can do

```
 library(raster)
 s <- stack(ff)
```

I am assuming that you simply need this stack for operations in R (it is an object, but not a file). You can extract the values in many ways (see the help files and vignette of the raster package). If you want a three dimensional array, you can do

```
 a <- as.array(s)
 dim(a)
 [1] 115  80  10
```

Answer (score 1):

thanks "**JEquihua**" for your suggestion, just need to add the initial variable before addLayer ie:

> for (i in 1:no){
>
> if (subs(filez[i],4)=="tiff"){
>
> image <- raster(filez[i]) # fill up raster stack with only the tiffs
>
> ```
>      imagestack <- addLayer(imagestack,image)
> ```
>
> }
>
> }

And sorry "**RobertH**", I'm newbie about R. I will be ask, more sure or exact by next time.

Also, any suggestions for extracting data from time series of MODIS images stacked. Or examples of libraries: "rts ()", "ndvits ()" or "bfast ()"

Greetings to the entire community.

Comment: If you liked the response could I perhaps get an accept on my answer? :) . I too am looking for examples of the bfast library so let me know if you have any luck on your search. There is a MODIS R package wich promises some really cool functionalities but I have not yet been able to install it properly. It's still in development: http://stevemosher.wordpress.com/modis-for-r/

Comment: Dear "JEquihua", we're here to help.
I have some papers on the library "bfast", and I'm also looking at the possibility of working with the package "MODIS" (which I installed on the operating system GNU / Linux Debian and runs correctly).
On the other hand as the package "MODIS" depends on "rgdal" maybe have an idea of ​​what your problem, which you can not install. (this is in linux)

this is my mail to send you the papers, lroblesr@unmsm.edu.pe

greetings from Peru.

Comment: Here more information of this thema (MODIS):                         https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=1252
http://www.spatial-analyst.net/wiki/?title=Download_and_resampling_of_MODIS_images
http://www.r-bloggers.com/modis-r-package-tutorial/
http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/modiscloud/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Another method for stacking

```
 library(raster)       
 list<-list.files("/PATH/of/DATA/",pattern="NDVI",
            recursive=T,full.names=T)
 data_stack<-stack(list)
```